# how to remove sidekiq stuck job on heroku?

Tags: heroku, sidekiq

Some image resize jobs failed to exit when our heroku background worker was restarted.

The job is stuck in the busy page of the UI.  It looks likes it is occupying one of the busy threads and was started over an hour ago.

But upon inspecting the job args and checking the DB, it looks like the images were actually processed, so maybe it's just redis, or the web UI contains wrong data.

Given the TID, and JID  osuuiyruo   8e25ebc62ae7d7023a9b5650

Is there anyway to remove these "stuck" jobs?  I tried quieting the workers and stopping them, and then scaling heroku workers to 0 then bringing them back up, but they stay in that stuck busy queue.

Answer (score 0):

Please state your Sidekiq version in the future.

If you are on 3.x, this will be fixed in 3.1.4. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1764

Comment: We're on sidekiq pro 1.7.3 and sidekiq 3.1.3